# How Can I randomly display/print/select 4 elements in a list without repetition in C#?

Tags: c#, list, select, random

```
 
            List<string> topLevel = new List<string>();
            

          


            topLevel.Add("000");
            topLevel.Add("100");
            topLevel.Add("200");
            topLevel.Add("300");
            topLevel.Add("400");
            topLevel.Add("500");
            topLevel.Add("600");
            topLevel.Add("700");
            topLevel.Add("800");
            topLevel.Add("900");
```

I tried with while loops, for loops and LINQ, but got nothing to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it by leveraging LINQ:

```
topLevel.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(4);
```

By sorting by `Guid.NewGuid()`, we are effectively randomizing the list. Afterwards, we return the top 4. If we are concerned that the list itself may contain duplicates, then we can use `Distinct()` to remove the duplicates:

```
topLevel.Distinct().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(4);
```

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBuj53
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I get a 'System.Linq.Orderedpartition' error

Comment: @luckyZelm then something is being done mistakenly or maybe there are other relevant details you have not shared? That code compiles and runs fine on my machine.

Comment: I even created a console application just to try again and it wouldn't work. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I have created a console application as well and it does work. Are you sure you have the code written exactly as above? See this .NET Fiddle showing that it does work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBuj53

Comment: I can confirm that the solution by @digital_jedi  works perfectly.

Comment: @digital_jedi Hi, it does work now. I wanted to know how you would add these elements to a listBox (one element on each line of the listbox) thanks

Comment: @luckyZelm if this is working, please mark the answer as an accepted answer. As for the listbox items, if you are talking about a WinForms listbox, you can do as so: `listBox.Items.AddRange(randomTop4.ToArray());`. If you are talking about a WPF listbox, you would need to bind the box's items to an ObservableCollection property in your view model, and then update that property with the random values.

Comment: @digital_jedi I am using a WPF listBox and i get this error

Comment: I do this :     var random=  topLevel.Distinct().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(4);
            lst2.Items.AddRange(random.ToArray()); and AddRange is underlined

Comment: @digital_jedi sorry to ask you so many question btw